# Go to previous page after submitting a form to a PHP file with a div loaded to specific content

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a logic problem maybe:

1. I have a page that has a div called #content,
2. in which I've loaded another page that has a form to submit data* (I have other pages loaded into the same #content but not "active" at the same time, because one of them are loaded on a click event via AJAX)
3. Data* that another PHP file processes.

when the process ends in that PHP file, I want to get back to the previous page so, I use:

```
> header('Location: '.$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

But, (the problem comes up here.)

When I get back into my main page that holds that famous #content div. the page loaded into the #content isn't the exactly previous one, so this is very annoying when the user works on it, because they need to click again the desired button to be loaded into #content.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are in your code. I think the good solution is to use `$_seesion` and store your information inside. When you reload the main page, check simply is value exist.

**Page 1**

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['page2'])
{
 echo "we come to page 2";
 unset($_SESSION['page2'])
}
```

**Page 2**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['page2'] = 1;
```

You can get more informations about session here:
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: with pleasure :) if this resolve your issue, please validate this

Comment: This doesnt work for me, but i made a js variable, and show the div deppending of this variable that is setted on click events, thats how i solve the problem